# NextJS Image src Ipfs link Error，next.js13

Tags: next.js, ipfs

I upload img to ifps and  successfully got cid.I visit this ipfs link by chrome and img dom src is ok, but failed in next Image. reaseon: connnet EIMEDOUT. Why? how to solve it?

```
setImageUrl(`https://ipfs.io/ipfs/${cid}`)
```

```
{imageUrl && <Image src={imageUrl} className="rounded-3xl" layout="fill" objectFit="cover" alt='加载失败' />}
```

[image]

I hope can help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the same problem, using the following method to load the image

```
    const [src, setSrc] = useState('');

      useAsyncEffect(async ()=> {
        let response = await fetch('https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmWUYn8w1tXKXWrx7KHEC5ofAtUkGyThVHBRSgy8R8bLad') as Blob;
        const blob = await response.blob();
        const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blobData);
        setSrc(objectURL)
      }, [setSrc])

    return(
      <Image
        loading='lazy'
        width={380}
        height={542}
        src={src}
        alt={raffle.Name}
      />
     )
```

Hope that helps